# error: implicit declaration of function 'execl' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to use execl call to execute a binary in [kernel-space-driver (driver.c)](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/drivers/usb/core/driver.c) at this point(line no. 850 onward):

```
    if (!retval)

{
        pr_info("%s: registered new device driver %s\n",
            usbcore_name, new_udriver->name);
 execl("binarylocation", "binary", NULL);

}
```

I have also added the #include < linux/unistd.h> in the file.

But when the kernel is build I get the following error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'execl' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

and thus the kernel failed to built.

And one warning is coming:

```
 warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'execl' [enabled by default]
```

Why are these errors and warning coming, even though the required header files are included?

Comment: I'd say one cannot run a process using the `exec*()` family of functions from kernel space. There seems to be another API to do so: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html

Answer (score 2):

`execl` is provided by libc, which is user-mode. In addition, `exec` functions replace the current process, but that context in the kernel doesn't really have a "current process" you'd want to be replacing.

The correct way to do this would be through a [udev rule](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run). If you really don't want to use udev for some reason, you can use the [usermode helper API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-call-usermodehelper-setup.html) ([example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw97Kernel-APIs-P1dth-LX)).